# Run only the first Bash command of multiple inline commands

Tags: bash, ssh, sh

I have a program which runs certain commands over SSH. Some of the commands are static (always the same) and others have arguments which change between runs. The program uses a private key to connect to the server, and the authorized key is locked down to force the command "sh run_script.sh".

run_script.sh will only run $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND if it matches a set of static commands, or if it begins in a certain way (for non-static commands).

The problem is that something like

```
allowedCommand arg1 arg2 && rm -r ~/
```

would probably slip through.

Is it possible to have bash only run the first command, and ignore anything after a pipe or &&?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to set a wrapper script as the login shell (instead of `/bin/bash`) and have it use `sed` or something to strip the unwanted parts off. It would be subject to possible false positives and may fail for arguments that contain whitespace and in other situations (see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).

There might be unforeseen security issues that are introduced by this approach.

It would be better to use the security features provided by `ssh`, `sudo`, a restricted shell such as `rbash` and other security facilities provided by the operating system in combination.